# How to export the output in json file from the type class generated from model.fit in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the pandas python library and I am getting the output as shown here, i have tried many things but failed to export this data in any of the file format. It's datatype is "class". some help would be great.

```
type is: <class 'torchtuples.callbacks.TrainingLogger'>
  df_val['event'] = 1 -df_val['event']
0:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 2.8714,     val_loss: 2.8103
1:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 2.5350,     val_loss: 2.6134
2:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 2.2439,     val_loss: 2.2942
3:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.9070,     val_loss: 1.8731
4:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.6023,     val_loss: 1.5823
5:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.4352,     val_loss: 1.4798
6:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.3817,     val_loss: 1.4516
7:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.4061,     val_loss: 1.4409
8:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.3340,     val_loss: 1.4549
9:      [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.3578,     val_loss: 1.4659
10:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.3235,     val_loss: 1.4431
11:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.3122,     val_loss: 1.4380
12:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.3188,     val_loss: 1.4477
13:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.3031,     val_loss: 1.4472
14:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.3189,     val_loss: 1.4441
15:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.2897,     val_loss: 1.4493
16:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.3263,     val_loss: 1.4614
17:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.2982,     val_loss: 1.4591
18:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.2805,     val_loss: 1.4693
19:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.2781,     val_loss: 1.4669
20:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.2867,     val_loss: 1.4657
21:     [0s / 0s],              train_loss: 1.2902,     val_loss: 1.4653
```

the above output generated from

```
model = LogisticHazard(net, tt.optim.Adam(0.01), duration_index=labtrans.cuts)

log = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size, epochs, callbacks, val_data=val)
```

Comment: can you share more code, about which library you are using and how you produced this output

Comment: @anarchy the question is edited now.. i am using pandas library.